Field specifications for Solana token metadata JSON files
I am creating a Solana token, and I noticed that the URI in the token's metadata points to a JSON file. Can anyone tell me what are the requirements for the fields in this JSON file? I saw that some tokens have an "extensions" field that stores social media URLs, but I couldn't find any official documentation about this on the Solana website.  Is there any standard or best practice for the format of this JSON file?
{
  "name": "LAIKA",
  "symbol": "LAIKA",
  "description": "$Laika is used as a utility token for Laika games to unlock new game features, used for staking, whitelists for NFT mints, access to the future Laika Launchpad, Laika physical products including cards in Laika wallet and in future as gas for L1 Blockhain",
  "image": "https://arweave.net/7smNNSdqM9c7KHenWUskSeRtkDNnxFMSYIRVWn1p4G4",
  "extensions": {
    "website": "https://laika.org/",
    "twitter": "https://twitter.com/laika_org/",
    "telegram": "https://t.me/laika_org"
  }
}


Check out: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/token-standard
These are the fields that'll be contained in the offchain metadata uri
{
  "name": "string",  // Name of the token
  "description": "string",  // Description of the token
  "image": "string",  // URI pointing to the token's logo
  "animation_url": "string",  // (Optional) URI pointing to the tokens's animation
  "external_url": "string",  // (Optional) URI pointing to an external URL. This is where the social media or project website will be placed
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "string",  // The type of attribute
      "value": "string"  // The value for that attribute
    },
    // ... more attribute objects
  ],
  "properties": {
  "files": [
    {
      "uri": "string",  // The file's URI
      "type": "string",  // The file's type (e.g. image/png, video/mp4)
      "cdn": "boolean"  // (Optional) Whether the file is served from a CDN
    },
    // ... more file objects
  ],
  "category": "string"  // (Optional) A media category for the asset (e.g. video, image)
}

